# Selenium invalid argument exception - python

Tags: python, selenium

As a practice I am trying to create a simple took to scrape a website in python. Below is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

products=[] #List to store name of the product
prices=[] #List to store price of the product
ratings=[] #List to store rating of the product
driver.get("<a href='https://www.flipkart.com/laptops/~buyback-guarantee-on-laptops-/pr?sid=6bo%2Cb5g&uniqBStoreParam1=val1&wid=11.productCard.PMU_V2'></a>")

content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
for a in soup.findAll('a',href=True, attrs={'class':'_31qSD5'}):
    name=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'_3wU53n'})
    price=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK'})
    rating=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'hGSR34 _2beYZw'})
products.append(name.text)
prices.append(price.text)
ratings.append(rating.text) 

df = pd.DataFrame({'Product Name':products,'Price':prices,'Rating':ratings}) 
df.to_csv('products.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

The issue I am having is that it is throwing an exception in my webdriver manager and I am not sure how to figure it out.

```
====== WebDriver manager ======
Current google-chrome version is 90.0.4430
Get LATEST driver version for 90.0.4430
Driver [/Users/mpl07/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/mac64/90.0.4430.24/chromedriver] found in cache
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mpl07/Documents/scraper.py", line 12, in <module>
    driver.get("<a href='https://www.flipkart.com/laptops/~buyback-guarantee-on-laptops-/pr?sid=6bo%2Cb5g&uniqBStoreParam1=val1&wid=11.productCard.PMU_V2'></a>")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Do not include HTML link tags in the `driver.get()` method.

So it should be:

```
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/laptops/~buyback-guarantee-on-laptops-/pr?sid=6bo%2Cb5g&uniqBStoreParam1=val1&wid=11.productCard.PMU_V2")
```

Comment: There are multiple issues in your code, but yes, that was the big one that would fail right away